# How to tell if a co routine has already been played?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I would like to play one co routine if the alpha on an object is black and a different co routine if the alpha is white. This would be called from a public void.

So basically I have an object that when clicked on fades something in. Now when clicking another object I would like that object faded out but only if it's fading in already.

```
 public void fade()

{
    if objectname.material.color = (1f, 1f, 1f, 0f);

    StartCoroutine(OPTION1());


    if objectname.material.color = (1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);

    StartCoroutine(OPTION2());

}
```

Comment: why not just put a breakpoint and debug from visual studio

Comment: Could you add your code and what you tried so far?

Comment: Alright, mind giving us a more specific example of what you are trying to do?  Having a coroutine do different things depending on the alpha value of a color seems pretty simple, are you just trying to prevent it from doing it multiple times?  if so why not use a conditional, where you ensure it wont happen again like `if(ran == false) { ran = true; doCoroutinestuff();}`

Comment: I've just updated the question with some code. The code sample is what I'm trying to do but I don't know how to write it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each object is unique (not static and shared per instance), you could probably add a property to prevent any type of recursive or repeated call... internally set flag and clear when done... Something like

```
private bool _isFading;

public void fade()
{
    // Is the fading already doing its thing?  If so, get out
    if( _isFading )
       return;
    // nope, not yet, first time in, set flag to prevent subsequent calls
    // against this same object
    _isFading = true;

    if objectname.material.color = (1f, 1f, 1f, 0f);
       StartCoroutine(OPTION1());

    if objectname.material.color = (1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
       StartCoroutine(OPTION2());

    // reset now that the fading is complete
    _isFading = false;
}
```